# adding elements to list based on a condition

Tags: python, list, dictionary, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a dictionary `params`. Now I would like to create a list (of dictionaries) from `params`. This list has either one or two elements as sometimes I dont have both key/value pairs in `params`. So I would like to only add these element to the list if they exist in `params`. Is there a simple way to do that? I mean I know I could do an if else statement but I would like to use as little code as possible.

```
params={'key1':'bla1', 'key2':'bla2'}
```

I know this works but is there something with less code

```
if 'key1' not in params:
    list_ = [{'val2': params['key2']}]
elif 'key2' not in params:
    list_ = [{'val1': params['key1']}]
else:
    list_ = [{'val1': params['key1']}, {'val2': params['key2']}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension :

```
list_ = [{k:v} for k,v in params.items()]
```

Then rename the keys at the end :

```
list_['val1']=list_['key1']
del list_['key1']

list_['val2']=list_['key2']
del list_['key2']
```

Or you can just rename the keys during the list comprehension with a dictionnary giving the actual keys.

```
names={'key1':'val1', 'key2':'val2'}
list_ = [{names[k]:v} for k,v in params.items()]
```

Comment: `{k, v}` -> `{k: v}`

Comment: You're right, fixed.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention the keys of the list are not the same as the key of the dictionary (I edited it: val1 vs key1).

Comment: You can rename the keys at the end, see my edit.

Comment: hmm so it is not possible with an if else or sth a bit shorter?

Comment: See my edit for a shorter solution.